# How can we add web reference of ssl enabled web service in to another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, wcf

I want to add web reference of ssl enabled web service in order to generate proxy classes. when i am trying to do so, i am getting an exception "Unable to download wsdl".
I am adding web service reference from solution explorer with the help of wizard.

Here are screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your code. we can't help if we can see how your adding the WSDL to your application normally i would say disable the SSL verify/valid checks

Comment: Are you able to open the wsdl in the browser?

Comment: @S.Dav  yes i am able to open wsdl in the browser.